# How to pass multiple parameters to Azure Durable Activity Function

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

My orchestrator receives a payload, with that payload it contains instructions that need to be passed along with other sets of data to activity functions.

how do I pass multiple parameters to an activity function? Or do I have to mash all my data together?

```py
def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    
    # User defined configuration
    instructions: str = context.get_input()

    task_batch = yield context.call_activity("get_tasks", None)
    
    # Need to pass in instructions too
    parallel_tasks = [context.call_activity("perform_task", task) for task in task_batch]

    results = yield context.task_all(parallel_tasks)
    
    return results
```

The `perform_task` activity needs both the items from `task_batch` and the user input `instructions`

Do I do something in my `function.json`?

*Workaround*
Not ideal, but I can pass multiple parameters as a single Tuple

```py
something = yield context.call_activity("activity", ("param_1", "param_2"))
```

I then just need to reference the correct index of the parameter in the activity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems there's no text-book way to do it. I have opted to give my single parameter a generic name like `parameter` or `payload`.

Then when passing in the value in the orchestrator I do it like so:

```py
payload = {"value_1": some_var, "value_2": another_var}
something = yield context.call_activity("activity", payload)
```

then within the activity function, I unpack it again.

edit: Some buried documentation seems to show that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-error-handling?tabs=python

Comment: Fantastic spot!

Comment: how to unpack the params in the activity function?

Comment: @Pingpong it's just a dictionary, so in my example I would do `value = payload["value_1"]` and payload gets passed in to the activity as parameter.

Answer (score 9):

Just to add to @Ari's great answer, here code to pass data from client function (HTTP request in this case) all the way to activity function:

`Client -> Orchestrator -> Activity`

Client

```
async def main(req: func.HttpRequest, starter: str) -> func.HttpResponse:
    client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)

    req_data = req.get_json()
    img_url = req_data['img_url']
    payload = {"img_url": img_url}
    
    instance_id = await client.start_new(req.route_params["functionName"], None, payload)

    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")

    return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
```

Orchestrator

```
def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    input_context = context.get_input()
    img_url = input_context.get('img_url')

    some_response= yield context.call_activity('MyActivity', img_url)
    
    return [some_response]
```

Activity

```
def main(imgUrl: str) -> str:
    print(f'.... Image URL = {imgUrl}')

    return imgUrl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **@dataclass** and **@dataclass_json** class decorators for your input and output types, like this:

```
@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Command:
  param1: str
  param2: int


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Result:
  val1: str
  val2: int
```

and then you can use those in Azure Functions, e.g. in Activity ones:

```
def main(input: DownloadFileRequest) -> DownloadFileResponse:
  # function code
  result: DownloadFileResponse = DownloadFileResponse("some", 123)
  return result
```

This provides you with a clean API and descriptive code. Much better approach than using dictionaries, at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest the [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) as a viable option, and one which should also be a bit more lightweight alternative to *dataclasses-json*; it is lighter in the sense that it does not use external libraries like `marshmallow` for generating schemas. It also performs a little better FWIW anyway.

I didn't really understand the schema of the data as outlined in the question unfortunately, thus I decided to roll my own for the purposes of a quick and dirty demo, so check it out:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard

@dataclass
class Batman(JSONWizard):
  suit_color: str
  side: 'Sidekick'


@dataclass
class Sidekick:
  name: str
  mood: str

# usage
bats = Batman.from_dict({'suitColor': 'BLACK',
                         'side': {'Name': 'Robin', 'mood': 'Mildly depressed'}})

print(repr(bats)) 
# prints:
#   Batman(suit_color='BLACK', side=Sidekick(name='Robin', mood='Mildly depressed'))
print(bats.to_dict())
# prints:
#   {'suitColor': 'BLACK', 'side': {'name': 'Robin', 'mood': 'Mildly depressed'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Azure functions in Python, only in C#, but I am assuming that in addition to passing the values as a dict, you could also pass them as a tuple that can be restructured within the function.